# Python imports module but doesn't recognize it when i initiate it?

Tags: python, sockets

I honestly have no idea why this is happening, I assume due to it not being on stack-exchange it's a very n00by mistake on my part. so here's the error:

***s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'socket' referenced before assignment***

tcpServer.py

```
import socket

def Main():
    UID = 1001
    sockets = []
    users = [] ## create usernames list
    sessionLimit = input("session Queue Limit: ")

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('192.168.1.74', 12127))

    s.listen(sessionLimit) ## listen for 1 connection at a time

    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        sockets.append(c)
        users.append(c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
        print("Connection from " + str(addr))

        data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8') ## recieve 1024 bytes from client at a time, and then decode it into utf-8
        if not data:
            break

        temp == data
        temp.split(" ") 
        if temp[0] == "//": ## check to see if user has sent command
            if temp[1] == "msg":
                for i in range(len(users)):
                    if users[i] == temp[2]:
                        sockets[i].send((" ".join(temp[::2])).encode('utf-8'))
        else: ## else, send data to all users. Could just use s.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))
            for socket in sockets:
                socket.send(data.encode('utf-8')) ## send to sockets[socket]

        ##print("From connected user: " + data)
        ##data = data.upper()
        ##print("Sending: " + data)
        ##c.send(data.encode('utf-8'))

        ## command listening
        commands = input("-> ")
        commands.split(" ")

        if commands[0] == "exit":
            c.close() ## close connection
        elif commands[0] == "/msg":
            for i in range(len(users)):
                if users[i] == commands[1]:
                    sockets[i].send((" ".join(commands[::1])).encode('utf-8'))
    """
       elif commands[0] == "/rename": ## dont implement yet, due to users[] length changing
            for i in range(len(users)):
                if users[i] == commands[1]:
                    sockets[i].send("<server_" + UID + "> rename " + commands[2].encode('utf-8'))
        """
    c.close()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Main()
```

Thanks for any help !
- Jacob

Comment: Are you sure the version you're running is the version you pasted? This version, when I run it, just tells me that I can't bind to that address (which makes sense) but I don't get any UboundLocalError.

Comment: on my server: 3.4.3+ on my workstation: 3.5.1. The base code (creating and binding the socket) ran perfect on the server, however since I've added the commands and multiple user features it for some reason wont accept; socket.socket()

Comment: Sorry, I mean, have you tried running this exact code? Because when I run it, there's no problem with socket.socket()

Comment: I tried running it and the code only gave an error for the bind aswell, however the indenting is all wrong, therefore the code won't function anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the variable name `socket` in the context of your `Main()` function when you do the following code block:

```
    for socket in sockets:
        socket.send(data.encode('utf-8')) ## send to sockets[socket]
```

That's causing an naming issue with the `socket` library. If you change that to:

```
    for sock in sockets:
        sock.send(data.encode('utf-8')) ## send to sockets[socket]
```

It will start to work. I also had to indent your code differently to ensure it was all in the `Main()` function you set up, and had to ensure the `input()` was parsed as an int. For reference, here's the full code block working for me:

```
import socket

def Main():
    UID = 1001
    sockets = []
    users = [] ## create usernames list
    sessionLimit = int(input("session Queue Limit: "))

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('192.168.1.74', 12127))
    s.listen(sessionLimit) ## listen for 1 connection at a time

    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        sockets.append(c)
        users.append(c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
        print("Connection from " + str(addr))

        data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8') ## recieve 1024 bytes from client at a time, and then decode it into utf-8
        if not data:
            break

        temp == data
        temp.split(" ") 
        if temp[0] == "//": ## check to see if user has sent command
            if temp[1] == "msg":
                for i in range(len(users)):
                    if users[i] == temp[2]:
                        sockets[i].send((" ".join(temp[::2])).encode('utf-8'))
        else: ## else, send data to all users. Could just use s.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))
            for sock in sockets:
                sock.send(data.encode('utf-8')) ## send to sockets[socket]

        ##print("From connected user: " + data)
        ##data = data.upper()
        ##print("Sending: " + data)
        ##c.send(data.encode('utf-8'))

        ## command listening
        commands = input("-> ")
        commands.split(" ")

        if commands[0] == "exit":
            c.close() ## close connection
        elif commands[0] == "/msg":
            for i in range(len(users)):
                if users[i] == commands[1]:
                    sockets[i].send((" ".join(commands[::1])).encode('utf-8'))
        """
        elif commands[0] == "/rename": ## dont implement yet, due to users[] length changing
            for i in range(len(users)):
                if users[i] == commands[1]:
                    sockets[i].send("<server_" + UID + "> rename " + commands[2].encode('utf-8'))
        """
    c.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: So stupid of me, I knew it would be something simple. I tried looking for uses of the variable socket, should have seen this. Cheers anyways !  -Jacob